# Right answer, wrong explanation, probability of grids?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math, solution-verification

> Two unit squares are selected at random without replacement from an $n\times n$ grid of unit squares. Find the least positive integer $n$ such that the probability that the two selected squares are horizontally or vertically adjacent is less than $\frac{1}{2015}$.

Here is my reasoning, I believe it is incorrect, but please help me out why.

> I fixed a square $x$. To get an adjacent square, there are $4$ options (above, below, right, left) to get an adjacent square. And there are $n^2 - 1$ squares to choose from (since $x$ has been chosen). I set up: $$\frac{4}{n^2 - 1} < \frac{1}{2015}$$

In the end I got $90$, which is correct, but I think the method is incorrect?

Comment: Well, you are ignoring the boundaries.  On the edges (and corners) your count of 4 adjacencies is wrong.  If you want to argue that these are too low probability to matter, you need to prove that.

Comment: Yes, you have to consider that the first square may be a border square, (in which the 4 corner squares are again a separate category)

Comment: @lulu, then would casework work? Case1: corner, case2: inside?

Comment: Absolutely. Corners, Edges (non-corners), Interior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your argument doesn't work is that the corner and edge squares of the grid are NOT adjacent to $4$ squares each. Edge squares are adjacent to $3$, and corners are adjacent to $2$.

Instead, a good strategy would be: (1) count the number of PAIRS of squares that are adjacent (horizontally or vertically); (2) count the number of total pairs of squares; and then divide (1) by (2).
If you do this you get
$$
\frac{\underbrace{(n-1) \cdot n}_{\text{horizontally adjacent}} + \underbrace{n \cdot (n-1)}_{\text{vertically adjacent}}}{n^2 \choose 2}
= \frac{4 n (n-1)}{n^2 (n^2 - 1)}
= \frac{4}{n(n+1)}
$$
Then you solve
$$
\frac{4}{n(n+1)} < \frac{1}{2015} \iff n(n+1) > 8060 \iff n \ge \boxed{90}.
$$

Comment: Where did you get: $(n-1)n + n(n-1)$?

Comment: Great answer; I think it should be $\frac{4}{n(n +1)}$ as $n^2 - 1 = (n - 1)(n+1)$, and you canceled out the $n - 1$.

Comment: @MarcusM Ah! Thanks, I knew that there must have been an error. The answer is now $n \ge 90$ as expected.

Comment: @6005, how do you get the numerator?

Comment: @Amad27 The number of pairs of squares that are horizontally adjacent is $(n-1)n$, because each row has $(n-1)$ such pairs, and there are $n$ rows. Same for the number of pairs that are vertically adjacent.

Comment: @6005, great point, it would be great to see a proof of that, I'll try to work on it.

Comment: @Amad27 Another way you can think of it is: every square except those in the last column is the left half of exactly one horizontally adjacent pair. So the number of horizontally adjacent pairs is the same as the number of squares not in the last column.

Comment: Using induction, there are $(n-1)$ pairs for $nxn$ square, and then there is one extra row added (for a $n+1xn+1$ square.)  so that is another pair, induction is true.

Answer (score 0):

There are $(n-1)n$ ways for your chosen squares to be adjacent horizontally, and the same number of ways to be adjacent vertically.

There are $n^2(n^2-1)/2$ ways to choose the two squares.

Taking $n=89$ gives a probability of $1/2002.5$ and $n=90$ gives $1/2047.5$.

So, you did get the correct answer.

The argument you made works only for squares away from the edges.  If you're on a non-corner edge, then you only have three choices.  If you're on one of the four corners, you only have two.

So, you're overestimating the probability.  But does it ever change the answer?  As it turns out, yes.  Had the probability been $1/2026$ instead of $1/2015$ the correct answer would still have been $90$, but your approximation would have told you the answer was $91$.

So, yes, under different circumstances, your method would have given the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

If we exclude $\frac 12$ the corner squares and $\frac14$ of the border squares from the count,

**say the whole of the left column**, our count will be correct, and the Pr equation will be:

$$\frac {4n(n-1)}{n^2(n^2-1)} = \frac{4}{n(n+1)}< \frac{1}{2015}$$